# Save the DOM tree of an HTML page

Tags: html, dom

I am trying to generate the DOM tree of a page to save it in a file like this:

```
html
  head
  body
    div.classA
      div.classB
    div.classC
```

Do you know some cool tool o bookmarklet to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get DOM tree with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042798/get-dom-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: Can that script work as a bookmarklet?